# Python server response codes

Tags: python, multithreading, http, ip, httpresponse

Is there a way in python to check the server response codes (200, 301, 404) in the header of a specified ip range (1.1.1.1 - 1.1.1.254) maybe its even possible to do it multi-threaded?

P.S. fond out that its possible with the "HTTPResponse.status" object (http://docs.python.org/library/httplib.html) how could i now check the ip range with it?

P.S. May be it would be a good idea to first check if port 80 is open and then only test the ones with open ports i think it would speed it really up because of 254 ip's maybe 30 are using port 80.

Answer (score 2):

You can just try and connect with a normal GET request to the root of the host, with a short timeout (or longer one if you want it to wait more). Then you can run it through a map.

```
import httplib
from multiprocessing import Pool

def test_ip(addr):
    conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(addr, timeout=1)
    try: 
        conn.request("GET", "/")
    except:
        return addr, httplib.REQUEST_TIMEOUT
    else:
        resp = conn.getresponse()
        return addr, resp.status
    finally:
        conn.close()

p = Pool(20)

results = p.map(test_ip, ["1.1.1.%d" % d for d in range(1,255)], chunksize=10)
print results

# [('1.1.1.1', 408), ('1.1.1.2', 408), ...]
```

Adjust `Pool` size and `chunksize` to suit.

Comment: Thanks for the code but please DON'T RUN THIS SCRIPT :) it froze my PC 2 times. It starts a few thousand of processes and even when you close it it continues. I have a pretty good PC (4*4,0 GHz 8GB Ram) and it doesn't work for me :) or do i do some thing wrong i adjusted the Pool size to the minimum and still kills my PC :(

Comment: Are you serious? It only starts Pool(size) number of processes. If you set it to 1 it should only be 1. Works just fine for me.

Comment: I would recommend opening a shell, and simply creating and pool, then check your process monitor and see how many python processes were created. They get initialized when you create the pool